# iframe refuses to display

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to load a simple iframe into one of my web pages but it is not displaying.  I am getting this error in Chrome:

```
Refused to display 'https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com".


Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do': 'ALLOW-FROM https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
```

This is the code for my iframe:

```
<p><iframe src="https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/" width="680" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
```

I am not really sure what that means. I have loaded plenty iframes before and never received such errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It means that the http server at `cw.na1.hgncloud.com` send some http headers to tell web browsers like Chrome to allow iframe loading of that page (https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/) only from a page hosted on the same domain (cw.na1.hgncloud.com) :

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com
```

You should read that :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Does resource which is used in `src` an attribute of `iframe` should send `Content-Security-Policy`?

Comment: `ALLOW-FROM` in used with `X-Frame-Options` is now obsolete as per Mozilla guidance, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options. You should prefer `Content-Security-Policy` as mentioned above.

Comment: I had a situation when the response header `Content-Security-Policy`  contain the allowed URL `my-site.com:*` but I try to set `www.my-site.com` to the iframe `src` attribute. So, these 3  letters WWW were the problem.

Answer (score 24):

The reason for the error is that the host server for https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com has provided some HTTP headers to protect the document. One of which is that the frame ancestors must be from the same domain as the original content. It seems you are attempting to put the iframe at a domain location that is not the same as the content of the iframe - thus violating the Content Security Policy that the host has set.

Check out this link on [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

For any of you calling back to the same server for your IFRAME, pass this simple header inside the IFRAME page:

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'`

Or, add this to your web server's CSP configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was that the site i was embedding had a specific url for embedding content and a different url for sharing

the url i had set in the iframe was

```
https://site/share/2432423232
```

changing it to

```
https://site/embed/2432423232
```

worked for me

Comment: Certainly YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue appears to me, **don't open the page in a private window.**

You can use multiple browsers if you need to log in with different users.