# Whats wrong with configuration CSP and iframe

Tags: apache, iframe, cross-domain, content-security-policy

I have my virtual host machine on Apache2
I write Headers in site config:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM *.yaad.net"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "child-src 'self' *.yaad.net; frame-ancestors *.yaad.net"
```

But still I get a bug in the browser.[Error in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LZQj.jpg)

I don't understand how I can escaped from this error! I already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944552/iframe-refuses-to-display)

What about I forgot ar forgot add?

Comment: What is the main domain? What's the domain being embedded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be closed! I found a solution - this error concern on the service than provides me service - it send Headers to me only on exact domain name.
Thank all, for reading.

Comment: Accept your own response as Answer to close