# Trying to get an embedded weblink or iframe to display another website

Tags: html

I'm trying to get a web link to display a website but I keep getting a "workplace.facebook.com refused to connect." in my display.

I tried doing an iframe and also the embed code and both display the same thing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <embed src="https://workplace.facebook.com" style="width:500px; height: 
    300px;">

</body>

</html>
```

The output should be the main website of workplace Facebook which will be displayed on TVs around my work. The reason why I need this to work like this is so I can refresh the page after 20 minutes and have it so it automatically scrolls down slowly. These expectations are not the problem just the web link not displaying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe refuses to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944552/iframe-refuses-to-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites do not allow external hosts to display their websites inside an iFrame, they block these requests using an X-frame Options message of SAMEORIGIN which only allows them to be displayed on sites with the same domain as the website itself.

Facebook, for example, won't allow Iframes from anywhere but facebook.com

If you use the inspect element on most modern browsers you should be able to see an error message similar to this:

> Refused to display 'https://www.work.facebook.com/' in a frame because
>   it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah i inspected and see it in console. So there is really no way to do what i want, correct?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I know of. It may be worth looking into Facebook APIs, they may have a feature that allows you to display some information, but I doubt it would be the entire website.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the HTTP server at workplace.facebook.com send some HTTP headers to tell web browsers like Chrome to allow iframe loading of that page (https://workplace.facebook.com) only from a page hosted on the same domain (workplace.facebook.com).