# Inline Frame refuses to show the Page I added in the Parameters

Tags: java, wicket

I want to show a WebPage on another WebPage using InlineFrame.

I initialized it like this:

Wicket/ Java:

```
InlineFrame choosenTestcaseInlineFrame =
  new InlineFrame("inlineFrame", AuthenticationPage.class);
    
public WhatToDoPage() {

        Form whatToDoForm = configureWhatToDoForm();
        add(whatToDoForm);
        add(choosenTestcaseInlineFrame.setOutputMarkupId(true));
        add(choosenTestcaseInlineFrame);

    }
```

'
HTML:

```
<iframe wicket:id="inlineFrame"  style="margin-left: 200px; height: 500px; width: 1000px">
```

The Problem is That the InlineFrame seems to refuse to show the Content.

here is a Screenshot:
[image: The Failure Message says "localhost refuses to connect"]

Comment: Hi,
does it work with another page (I mean other than AuthenticationPage). I also see that you add choosenTestcaseInlineFrame twice: you can remove the last 'add(choosenTestcaseInlineFrame);'

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. No it doesnt work with the other Pages as well. Yes i added it twice with different methods to make sure its properly added.

Comment: Then I would take a look at browser debugger to check if there's any error loading the iframe page. Maybe your browser is blocking iframe for security policy (?)

Comment: Wow Tank you there is an error written. it says "Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/authentication?11' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.​" Do you know were i can allow this? I am using Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Chrome has a specific option to allow iframe to be displayed, but you might find some clues to solve the problem here:

[iframe refuses to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944552/iframe-refuses-to-display)