# How to have Amazon website iframed in our website

Tags: html, iframe

I m trying to add amazon site in my website using iframe. But it fails by giving me the message as `www.amazon.com refused to connect.`.

However other websites are working fine for the same iframe code.

iframe code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.amazon.com" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
```

Any help on explaining this mystery and possibly helping me add the amazon site as iframe is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can see a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944552/iframe-refuses-to-display). Its the sites security settings I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your **embed code** in Chrome and saw the following error:

```
www.amazon.com refused to connect.
```

It means that the origin server does not authorize you to show this content inside an `iframe`.

The amazon product details page request returns the following response header:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

The [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid [click-jacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

The added security is provided only if the user accessing the document is using a browser that supports `X-Frame-Options`.

Answer (score 0):

The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a , ,  or . Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

The added security is provided only if the user accessing the document is using a browser that supports X-Frame-Options.

**Syntax**

There are two possible directives for X-Frame-Options:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Setting X-Frame-Options inside the  element is useless! For instance,  has no effect. Do not use it! X-Frame-Options works only by setting through the HTTP header, as in the examples below.

```
<iframe src="https://www.amazon.com" width="800" height="600">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny"
</iframe>
```