# How to prevent resize and maximize of Javascript window

Tags: javascript, html

How do I prevent resizing and maximizing of the Javascript window?

I am using the following code:

```js
var win = window.open(myURL, "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,dialog=yes,resizable=no,top=100,left=250,width=800,height=530");
```

Have tried multiple solutions from Stackoverflow but had no luck. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You cannot, and you absolutely **should not**. If you want to render a modal popup of fixed size, use a `<dialog>` with whatever dimensions you choose, *inside* your page. If you want control over your user's whole display, request fullscreen permissions from them.

Comment: Why not using a `<dialog>` with an `<iframe>` inside? What stops you from using this setup?

Answer (score 20):

## It is completely possible

<sup>... albeit limited</sup>

By listening for the [window `resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event and using the [`Window.resizeTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) function, it is possible to prevent the window from resizing.

```js
var x = window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com", "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,dialog=yes,resizable=no,top=100,left=250,width=800,height=530");
x.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    x.resizeTo(800, 530);
})
```

*This is not a cross-origin solution* - you cannot add event listeners etc,. on a window with a different origin as it can be used for malicious purposes.

Result:

[image: UnresizableWindow-NonCrossOriginEdition-SpectricSO]

[[Try it yourself]](https://spectricso.github.io/spectric-samples/67687288/sample1.html)

---

#### Supporting different-origin

The following solution creates a new window using the current URL, then overwrites the document with an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) containing the source of the desired site.

<sup>why do we first open using the current URL? So we can manipulate the DOM without being annoyed with these "Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame" errors, and also so that we can attach the resize event listener to the window (not possible with the original solution).</sup>

```js
var goto = "https://wix.com";
var x = window.open(location, "_blank", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,dialog=yes,resizable=no,top=100,left=250,width=800,height=530");
x.document.write(`<html><head><style>body{margin:0;overflow:hidden;}iframe{width:100%;height:100%;border:0}</style></head><body><iframe src="${goto}"></iframe></body></html>`);
x.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    x.resizeTo(800, 530);
})
```

Result:

[image: UnresizableWindow-CrossOriginEdition-SpectricSO]

[[Try it yourself]](https://spectricso.github.io/spectric-samples/67687288/sample2.html)

Which works on most sites. But you'll come across a "<sitename> refused to connect" once in a while.

If you want to know why, check out: [iframe refuses to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944552/iframe-refuses-to-display)

---

As for preventing maximization of the window, there does not seem to be any way to minimize it programmatically <sup>note: the `resize` event is fired during maximization</sup>. [`Window.minimize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/minimize) looks promising, but as of yet there is [no support for it across any browser](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_window_minimize).

Comment: Doesn't work. Nothing stops me from resizing my browser windows as I wish.

Comment: @Bergi The method should work if the site is on the same domain.

Comment: You could also call this from the opened page itself, not requiring same-domain access.

Comment: You may ask yourself: WHY do I need to do this. Don't force this on your users.

Comment: @Spectric this is not working at time window maximize.

Comment: Only one problem: When you drag to resize from top, it moves the window.

Comment: In Vivaldi, I can resize the new window. In Firefox, the popup blocker stops it from opening in the first place. In Chrome, [an extension](https://superuser.com/a/264151/175275) causes it to open in a new tab instead of a popup. It's a completely lost cause.

Answer (score 3):

You can not, in general. That's a feature controlled by browser configuration:

[Windows.open() MDN FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#faq):

**How do I turn off window resizability or remove toolbars?**

> You cannot force this. Users with Mozilla-based browsers have absolute control over window functionalities like resizability, scrollability and toolbars presence via user preferences in about:config. Since your users are the ones who are supposed to use such windows (and not you, being the web author), the best is to avoid interfering with their habits and preferences. We recommend to always set the resizability and scrollbars presence (if needed) to yes to insure accessibility to content and usability of windows. This is in the best interests of both the web author and the users.

The same goes for Google Chrome.

Comment: do we have any workaround example to fix this.

Comment: As noted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67781094/3388225) https://codepen.io/aleksxor/pen/ZEevJgK I guess that's the closest thing you can get. Though most of the time it looks really ugly. Also consider the fact that many sites have strict CSP rules against unknown/blob/etc frame-ancestors.

Comment: ... and it where bad times while you still could do such things ;)