# Why is the iframe src in my code not loading any page and saying that the page refused to connect?

Tags: html

I tried a source file path locally it didn't work and tried https://www.google.com and https://www.w3schools.com and https://www.facebook.com. It always gives an error saying the page ex google refused to connect?

```
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <h1>iFrame</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is probably due to configuration of your web server, i.e. security settings. Which web server are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iframe refuses to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944552/iframe-refuses-to-display)

Answer (score 1):

When I tried that code it gave me two errors saying:

#Error 1:

"Refused to frame 'https://www.w3schools.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://mycourses.w3schools.com"."

#Error 2:
chromewebdata/:1659 Blocked autofocusing on a  element in a cross-origin subframe.

That happened because the request to access W3Schools violated the Safety Policy Laws. People add that to there websites because hackers can use the Iframe and get out people's data.

Here is an Example:

If you try to make a Iframe on Google Account Login or Amazon or Facebook, Twitter, and other big compaines. They block the Iframe request because people may think that this website is the really website they were looking for but it was not true. Also, when a user tries to login in that Iframe hackers can use some JavaScript to get out the username and Password and hack the users account.

But if you really need to make an Iframe then on https://www.w3schools.com press two keys Ctrl + U to view the source code then you can copy it then paste it. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Like you can read [here](https://cgscomputer.com/block-iframes-how-to-stop-your-website-from-being-iframed/) it's possible to block iframes on your website. Google for example does that (if you use google as the src [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe) it blocks it aswell). W3Schools works, but thats because the iframe itself is also on W3Schools