# How to enable all iframes on a HTML page

Tags: html, iframe

I am searching for a way to allow any iframes on my own page, so I don't get the 'refused to connect' error. Is this possible using the meta tag? If so, can someone make a snippet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iframe refuses to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944552/iframe-refuses-to-display)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a way to display the entire page using PHP

Just write the code below :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('site url');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```