# How to Append 3rd party web page on own page?

Tags: php, iframe

I have a popup model, i am trying to append a website page on my popup model but I am getting this
intercom.help refused to connect.

Please Guide me how I can solve this issue.

```html
<a class="nav-link " href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#kb_modal">Knowledgebase</a>

<div class="modal right fade" id="kb_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="kb_modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#8CC63F">
        <button id="closebtn" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="margin-top:-5px;">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="https://intercom.help/inquiry-removers-518c2266c647/en/?q=submit" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried object, embed, and iframe tags, they are not working.

Comment: The server you are trying to frame in is sending headers instructing browsers to only allow certain domains to do that, and your site is not on that list. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31944552/231316